# Apply function to all items individually?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying to resize input fields on the fly using jQuery, my function works but applies the same value to each input as opposed to each input's width being declared independatly. Can anyone see what I may be doing wrong?

**jQuery**

```
function inputSize(){
   var inputContainer = $('.input-style').width();
   var labelWidth = $('.input-style label').width() + 40; // 40 is the padding + margin
   var inputNewSize = inputContainer - labelWidth;    
   $('.input-style input').css('width', inputNewSize);
}

inputSize();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/r76cgn6a/

Comment: `$('.input-style')` Returns all elements with `class=input-style`. Think about why getting the `width()` of that result might not be useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily convert your function to be an argument of `.each`. Simply change your selectors to `$(this)` or `$(this).find` depending of the case :

```
function inputSize(){
    var inputContainer = $(this).width();
    var labelWidth = $(this).find('label').width() + 40; // 40 is the padding + margin
    var inputNewSize = inputContainer - labelWidth;    
    $(this).find('input').css('width', inputNewSize);
}

$('.input-style').each(inputSize);
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r76cgn6a/2/)**

Comment: Q: Why not use an anonymous function in the `each` call instead of adding another function (that is unlikely to be reused by itself)?

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie Because I only change his code, tried to prove a point I guess. Also, if his code was in a function, maybe he reuse it? It could be in an anonymous call. I just demonstrated that his code needed little tweaks to work!

Comment: I prefer PeterKA's solution for elegance, but +1 for first working answer :)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie Of course, he totally won on the elegance!

Answer (score 2):

Your code is not considering the **context** of each `input` element; use the `this` to reference the target parent and `label` elements. Use `.width(function() { .. })` like so:

```
$('.input-style input').width(function() {
    return $(this).parent().width() - $(this).parent().find('label').width() - 40;
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/r76cgn6a/3/), [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/r76cgn6a/4/)

**And** since you may not re-use the defined function you may want to change your code to:

```
$(function() {
    $('.input-style input').width(function() {
        return $(this).parent().width() - $(this).parent().find('label').width() - 40;
    });
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/r76cgn6a/5/)

Comment: Lovely. Good use of the callback version of `width` :)

Answer (score 0):

Using $('.input-style').width() will take only the first element width.

If there're many elements then you need to use .each function, then use $(this) with your code like this:

```
$(".input-style").each(function(index,item){
    var inputContainer = $(this).width();
    var labelWidth = $(this).find("label").width() + 40; // 40 is the padding + margin
    var inputNewSize = inputContainer - labelWidth;    
    $(this).find("input").css('width', inputNewSize);
});
```

Comment: Still does not work: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/r76cgn6a/7/ You need to correct the last line: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/r76cgn6a/8/

Comment: Sorry I wrote it fast, fixed now

Answer (score -1):

Changed you code to use .each method which takes all the element of the same css class one by one:

```js
$(.input-style).each(function inputSize(){
    var inputContainer = $('.input-style').width();
    var labelWidth = $('.input-style label').width() + 40; // 40 is the padding + margin
    var inputNewSize = inputContainer - labelWidth;    
    $('.input-style input').css('width', inputNewSize);
});

inputSize();
```

```css
body {font-size:10px;}

.input-style {
    background: #e7e7e7;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 10px;
}
.input-style label {
    margin-right: 20px;
    font-family:'Raleway', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
  
    font-style: italic;
    color: #818181;
    font-size: 1.8em;
    float: left;
}
label {
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.input-style input {
    margin-right: 20px;
    font-family:'Raleway', sans-serif;
      background:yellow;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: italic;
    color: #818181;
    font-size: 1.8em;
    outline: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="input-style">
    <label>Name*</label>
    <input data-val="true" data-val-length="The field name must be a string with a maximum length of 500." data-val-length-max="500" data-val-required="Please complete this field" id="Name" name="Name" required="required" type="text" value="">
</div>
<div class="input-style">
    <label>Confirm Password*</label>
    <input data-val="true" data-val-equalto="passwords do not match" data-val-equalto-other="*.Password" data-val-length="The field re-enter password must be a string with a maximum length of 50." data-val-length-max="50" data-val-required="Please complete this field" id="ComparePassword" name="ComparePassword" required="required" type="password" value="">
</div>
```

Comment: You have put the original non-specific selectors inside your each, defeating the whole point of the `each`. Reference `this` for each element within the each.